# cURL saves cookie on one server, but will not save cookie on another server

Tags: php, api, curl, cookies

Ive never used cURL before and have run into an issue.

Im writing a small PHP script to interact with [Dotcom Monitor's API](https://wiki.dotcom-monitor.com/category/api-and-xml-interfaces/)

I'm using their [example code from here](https://wiki.dotcom-monitor.com/programming-interfaces/code-examples/) to make API requests which I rolled into this function (which is in a PHP class):

```
private function Request($action, $method, $data)
    {
        /**
         * Retrieves data from Dotcom Monitor API
         * @param string $action - dynamic url part
         * @param string $method - HTTP method POST/GET
         * @param string $data - POST data, 'null' for GET request, json_encode() is called on this param
         * @return stdClass object The response to the request
         */
        // setting request url (merging "constant" and "dynamic" part)
        $ch = curl_init($this->API_URL . $action);
        // setting HTTP method
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
        // return string
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        // ignoring SSL certificate
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        // Cookie management
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
        // creating request header array
        $headers = array('Content-Type: application/json');
        // checking if 'POST' method
        if($method === 'POST' && $data != null)
        {
            // encode input data to json
            $data_string = json_encode($data);
            // setting POST data
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
            // setting content length header
            array_push($headers, 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string));
        }
        // setting headers
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        // making request
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        // closing connection
        curl_close($ch);
        // returning deserialized json data as object
        return json_decode($result);
    }
```

Im calling the function like this:

```
$login = $this->Request('login', "POST", $this->$API_CREDENTIALS);
```

The way the API works is,

- you log in (with the call above)
- you are authenticated
- a cookie is stored in `cookie.txt`
- that authentication is valid for 60 seconds
- each subsequent call to the API restarts the 60 second timer

I am using this on my own server and everything works perfect, Im logged in, the cookie file is created, subsequent calls to the API read the cookie and those calls are allowed.

I can run it on phpFiddle and everything works perfect (exactly as above).

#### The problem:

However, when I upload the exact same code on a my work server, the login call succeeds but `cookie.txt` is **not** created which seems to silently fail all the API calls that come after the login.

#### What I've checked so far:

- No PHP errors are thrown (error reporting is enabled)
- cURL is enabled on the server
- cookies are enabled on the server
- the folder in question is apache/web writable

#### Server info

**Working server:**

- Configuration - apc Version  3.1.13
- PHP Version 5.4.19
- cURL support  enabled
- cURL Information  7.19.7

**Non-Working server:**

- Configuration - apache2handler Apache Version Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.4.16
- PHP Version 5.4.16
- cURL support  enabled
- cURL Information  7.29.0
- Apache Version    Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.4.16

Comment: The response header might have the PHP version in it, `X-Powered-By:`.

Comment: read/write permission problems?

Comment: @charlietfl not seemingly, IT confirmed that the folder is apache/web writable (forgot *writable* in the question, added it, TY)

Comment: Have the right `chmod`/file owner?

Comment: @Darren from our IT guy: *"changed group ownership and allowed write to group for apache user, t's certainly not generating that file anywhere but the apache user certainly has access. I just generated cookie.txt as the apache user and it worked so the permissions are good"*

Comment: Hrm, out of curiosity, could you run this for me on this script: `clearstatcache();
echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($THE_FILE_NAME)), -4);` and let me know the permissions. (*replace `$THE_FILE_NAME` with the path to this script*)

Comment: And if that fails, could you try an absolute path to the cookie file : `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath('cookie.txt'));`.

Comment: @Daren Tying the first one now, itll be a bit before I know though, this server uses saltstack to pull changes from Git every 30-45 mins or so (this is why I originally was working on a different server) for `$THE_FILENAME` should I use `/var/www/html/somesite.com/dotcommonitorapp/php/dcmManager.php`?

Comment: @DelightedD0D Yeah that looks about right, just the absolute path to the file.

Comment: @chris85 PHP version is PHP/5.4.16 thanks for that tip

Comment: @Darren it looks like IT broke saltstack while testing for me because none of my changes are propagating to the server now. Ill get back to you tomorrow with the results of the tests, thank you for your time

Comment: @Darren results of the test were `0644` but Im not sure what that means in this context, trying the `realpath()` now

Comment: Could you do the same test, but on the local instance where you said it was working and post that here too

Comment: @Darren on the server where it works I get `0604`

Comment: Are the 2 environments (local and live) the exact same? I.e. server, php version, same modules, etc etc?

Comment: @Darren no they are not. I have updated above with the information for each, please let me know if any other info is needed

Comment: @Darren Im still not sure what exactly caused the problem but the IT guys deleted `php.ini` then re created it and now everything works, thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define full (absolute) path to this files.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

Give full path to cookies.txt in a directory where the webserver has write access to it. For example /tmp/cookies.txt

Comment: Thanks, I have tried giving the full path and the folders are webserver writeable